# use ffmpeg to cut video,the video will have extra duration

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -ss 2 -i input.mp4 -c copy -t 5 out.mp4
```

after I executed the ffmpeg command.
the out.mp4 total have **7** seconds,it starts from the second frame of input.mp4 to the seventh frame of input.mp4.
It only has 5 effective seconds of the input.mp4, the last 2 seconds of input.mp4 is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ffmpeg -ss 00:00:02.00 -i input.mp4 -t 5  out_5seconds.mp4
```